# Using jQuery to find push all links in html to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

given a block of html that is a var, not on the actual document:

```
var html_cmt = "Check out this awesome link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui Check out this awesome link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui Check out this awesome link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui Check out this awesome link:"
```

I need to build an array of all links, I have the following but it's only building the first one, not all.

```
var hrefs = new Array();
hrefs.push( $("<div>").html(html_cmt).find('a').attr('href'));
```

Suggestions on how I can create an array of all the links, given html content that is not on the document just a JS var? thank you

Comment: AnApprentice. I just noticed that your `html_cat` variable doesn't contain any HTML tags. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .`.map` and `.get`: http://jsfiddle.net/tyggq/.

```
var hrefs = $("<div>").html(html_cmt).find("a").map(function() {
  return this.href;
}).get();

// find <a> elements, replace them with their hrefs, and
// convert the jQuery object to an array
```

The string should contain actual `<a>` elements though; you say it works for the first `<a>` element so I guess your string is different from what you posted.

Comment: Might want to assign the end result to a variable for clarity, but nicely done otherwise. +1

Answer (score 5):

```
var hrefs = [];
$("<div>").html(html_cmt).find('a').each(function(){
    hrefs.push(this.href);
    //         ^^^^^^^^^ Resolves URLs automatically. See notes
});
```

### Another approach:

```
var hrefs = $("<div>").html(html_cmt).find('a').map(function(){
    return this.href;
}).toArray();
```

### Notes

`this.href` will return the fully resolved UR, `$(this).attr('href')` will return the real attribute.

Example (assume `http://localhost/dir/test.php`):

```
this.href            == http://localhost/foo.bar
$(this).attr('href') == /foo.bar

this.href            == http://localhost/dir/test.php#doo
$(this).attr('href') == #doo

this.href            == http://localhost/file.do
$(this).attr('href') == ../file.do

this.href            == http://localhost/dir/
$(this).attr('href') == .
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure by what you mean by "If you want the real attr, use $(this).attr('href')" ?

Comment: @AnApprentice I have updated my answer to elaborate both methods. Unless you want to use possibly relative URLs, I recommend to use `this.href`.

Answer (score 1):

I did it too... just a lot slower then everyone else :)

```
var html = "Check out this awesome link: https://URL-1 Check out this awesome link: https://URL-2 Check out this awesome link: https://URL-3 Check out this awesome link:";

var urls = [];


do
{
    var start = html.indexOf("http");
    var end = 0;

    if (start > 0)
    {
        for (var i = start; i < html.length; i++)
        {
            if (html[i] == " ")
            {
                end = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        urls.push(html.substring(start, end));
    }

    html = html.substring(end, html.length);
}
while(start >= 0);

console.log(urls);
```

on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HfvyE/

Answer (score 0):

var links = $html_cmt.split("Check out this awesome link: ")